# Why did Gretel's fingers turn black?

Tags: plot-explanation, gretel-and-hansel

At the end of *Gretel and Hansel* (2020), Gretel is walking in the woods explaining that she can choose her own path, good or evil basically. The last thing we see is Gretel's fingers turn black, like the witch's fingers. It doesn't appear that Gretel is fully surprised by this.

Did her fingers turn black because she has chosen the evil path (or the evil path has chosen her), or did they turn black because she has accepted her powers regardless of her desired alignment?

I don't recall seeing the witch's daughter's fingers be black though we know she was evil.

Comment: Not explained in the movie and not very important. Either it's a sign of being a witch or doing evil (and yeah, Gretel killed the witch).

Answer (score 2):

Artistic liberties, really. It's sort of a sign that Gretal was accepting of her powers and began to fully use them. Kind of like dipping your fingers in a jar of paint, I guess. Either that or whoever was in charge of that decision was a Warhammer fan.